# Custom rounded shape image using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to get a custom-shape image as shown here:

[image: rounded image]

```css
#oval-shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="oval-shape" src="http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/internship_yourstory.jpg">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XDLVx/328/)

Any thoughts if this is even possible?

Comment: what do you mean "is this even possible"?  Didn't you just do it?  What about the DEMO you linked to isn't doing what you want?

Comment: No. The shape isn't right. The image has more curve towards the top.

Comment: Your question asks for an oval shape. The demo creates an oval shape.  The image in the question is not an oval shape.  I don't know what shape that is, but it's not an oval.  So you're saying you want to modify the demo to create the shape in the image in the question?  I suggest you rephrase your question to remove the confusion.

Comment: Do you know that the image you are showing as what you want is even using CSS to do this?

Comment: I don't know how to frame the question to sound it like I want. To answer mrunion, the design is made in photoshop. If it's done in css, i would copy-paste the code and won't be asking here!

Comment: You can obtain this custom shape with css masking. You can read more about it here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one way you can "fake" this shape with `border`:

```css
body {
  background: purple;
}
#oval-shape {
  display:block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/internship_yourstory.jpg" id="oval-shape">
```

Comment: Interesting. I used a transparent background and got it the way I want. I'm still trying to figure out how you manage to pull this off. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ElaineByene oh ! Thanks for point that ... I haven't tried the transparent bg just works :) .. the warning is wrong XD

Comment: After testing with another image (square), I realize this method distorts the original image :(

Comment: @ElaineByene that is for the fixed values on height and width ... maybe. Post it on a fiddle maybe I can help u; you can also use the img's as background and cover on divs.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below border properties and adjust as per your needs. More number means more towards circle. Hope it helps

```
#oval-shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border-top-left-radius:150px;
  border-top-right-radius:150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:80px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's far from what I want. Please check the screenshot again.

Comment: @ElaineByene That gives you an answer regarding the right way to make custom-shape images using css. You will have to experiment with the property values `px/%` yourself in order to find the shape closest to what you want. +1

Comment: No! I already had that and have played with it for hours before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

**You can indeed get that exact shape with no straight edges:** http://jsfiddle.net/XDLVx/339/

```
#oval-shape {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px / 70px 70px 30px 30px;
}
```

*More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp*

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative approach** with an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). The following example uses 2 [cubic bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) to make the desired shape and the [pattern element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) to fill the shape with the image:

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 8">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="10">
      <image xlink:href="http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/internship_yourstory.jpg" x="-1" y="0" width="14" height="7" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#img)" d="M0.7 5 C1 -0.8 9 -0.8 9.3 5 C9.3 7.5 0.7 7.5 0.7 5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution ... Seems like you really know about SVG. Can you guide me where to start with that?

Comment: @DaniP I would suggest to start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). If you want to chat about it or have questions, you can come to [this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/svg-css-shapes-and-designs), people will help if they can.

Answer (score 0):

Sure...here you go. Adjust as required.

```css
#oval-shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/internship_yourstory.jpg" id="oval-shape">
```

Comment: No. This isn't what I'm looking for. Also, I have been trying to adjust as required/shown in the screenshot here. The adjustment is what is making me go nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
#ovalshape{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(51% 27%, 71% 36%, 91% 53%, 89% 68%, 76% 78%, 49% 85%, 16% 78%, 8% 65%, 15% 46%, 33% 33%);
    clip-path: polygon(51% 27%, 71% 36%, 91% 53%, 89% 68%, 76% 78%, 49% 85%, 16% 78%, 8% 65%, 15% 46%, 33% 33%);
}
```

Option 2:
Take the image you want and cut out the inside and make transparent.

```
 <div style="height: 100; width: 100; overflow: hidden; background-image: url'picture.jpg';>
     <img src="cutout.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. what is `src="cutout"`? and what is `clip-path`?

Comment: on that image you posted, at the person and cut them out and make it transparent.  then save the image as cutout.png and use that for the source.

Clip-path has nothing to do with option two, they are do different options.

Comment: cutting out is out of question since it will be a dynamic image in JPG format. Can you give a demo of that clip-path? I fail to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#oval-shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="oval-shape" src="http://d152j5tfobgaot.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/internship_yourstory.jpg">
```

Comment: What's the point of this answer? Isn't it same as the code in question?

Answer (score 0):

```
#oval-shape {
    width: 18%;
    height: 209px; 
    background: blue; 
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%/* border-radius: 100px / 50px; */
    border-radius: 50%;
```

}

try with different height and width according to you shape. I think this will work

Comment: you should delete this answer

Comment: @GCyrillus  Can u suggest me please y should i delete this answer and what is the best way to answer?

Comment: You should indent the code you put in answser (for readability) and explain a little what it is about, so answer has some value. As it is , you have been lucky that no one downvoted it :) I just edited your answer for the code part, and you can notice easy what it is about and that there is something wrong with the syntaxe .. last 2 lines won't be of any use ;)

Answer (score 0):

as others answers , border-radius can do it:

demo below, with both image on top of each others and side by side:

```css
img {
  border-radius:200px 200px 180px 180px / 190px 190px  80px 80px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div img {
  opacity:0.5
}
div {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nGL.png);
  display:inline-block;
  padding:12px;
}
.dem {
  margin:15px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 10px white;
  }
body {
  background:#333;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/100/people/9" />
</div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/140/100/people/9" class="dem"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nGL.png" />
```

[image: snippet screenshot]